# Validate custom JSON schema

Tags: python, json, validation, schema

I'm trying to validate a custom JSON schema in Python 3. I'm using [this tutorial](https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step) from *JSON Schema* and validating it with an online tool, [JSON Schema validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/), that is one of the tools that they refer to in the [*Web (Online)* section of the *Implementation* section](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-web%20(online)).

After defining my JSON schema, filling out an example and testing it in the online tool, it says it's fine. But the problem is that if I change the names of the nodes (except for the main node), it keeps saying that it's OK. That's what I don't understand.

I had defined the scheme like this (and it is wrong). I apologise if it is difficult to understand because I had to anonymise the data:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://my-program/schema.json",
  "title": "A title",
  "description": "A description",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "root": {
      "description": "A description",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": false,
      "properties": {
        "a": {
          "description": "A description",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "b": {
          "description": "A description",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "c": {
          "description": "A description",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "d": {
          "description": "A description",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "d_a": {
              "description": "A description",
              "type": "object"
            },
            "d_b": {
              "description": "A description",
              "type": "object"
            },
            "d_c": {
              "description": "A description",
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "d_c_a": {
                  "description": "A description",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "d_c_a_a": {
                      "description": "A description",
                      "type": "array",
                      "items": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "minItems": 0,
                      "uniqueItems": false
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [
                    "d_c_a_a"
                  ]
                },
                "d_c_b": {
                  "description": "A description",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "d_c_b_a": {
                      "description": "A description",
                      "type": "array",
                      "items": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "minItems": 0,
                      "uniqueItems": false
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [
                    "d_c_b_a"
                  ]
                },
                "d_c_c": {
                  "description": "A description",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "d_c_c_a": {
                      "description": "A description",
                      "type": "array",
                      "items": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "minItems": 0,
                      "uniqueItems": false
                    },
                    "d_c_c_b": {
                      "description": "A description",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [
                    "d_c_c_a",
                    "d_c_c_b"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "d_c_a",
                "d_c_b",
                "d_c_c"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "d_a",
            "d_b",
            "d_c"
          ]
        },
        "e": {
          "description": "A description",
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object"
          },
          "minItems": 1,
          "uniqueItems": true,
          "properties": {
            "e_a": {
              "description": "A description",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "e_b": {
              "description": "A description",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "e_c": {
              "description": "A description",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "e_d": {
              "description": "A description",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "e_e": {
              "description": "A description",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "e_f": {
              "description": "A description",
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "e_a",
            "e_b",
            "e_c",
            "e_d",
            "e_e",
            "e_f"
          ]
        },
        "f": {
          "description": "A description",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "g": {
          "description": "A description",
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "h": {
          "description": "A description",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "h_a": {
              "description": "A description",
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "minItems": 0,
              "uniqueItems": true
            },
            "h_b": {
              "description": "A description",
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "minItems": 0,
              "uniqueItems": true
            },
            "h_c": {
              "description": "A description",
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "minItems": 0,
              "uniqueItems": true
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "h_a",
            "h_b",
            "h_c"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e",
        "f",
        "g",
        "h"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "root"
  ]
}
```

And the JSON that I'm trying to validate looks like:

```
{
  "root": [
    {
      "a": "Bla bla",
      "b": "Bla bla",
      "c": "Bla bla",
      "d": {
        "d_a": {
          "something random": 0,
          "something random": 4
        },
        "d_b": {
          "something random": "Bla bla",
          "something random": 0
        },
        "d_c": {
          "d_c_a": {
            "d_c_a_a": [
              "something random"
            ]
          },
          "d_c_b": {
            "d_c_b_a": [
              "something random",
              "something random",
              "something random"
            ]
          },
          "d_c_c": {
            "d_c_c_a": [
              "something random"
            ],
            "d_c_c_b": "something random"
          }
        }
      },
      "e": [
        {
          "e_a": "something random",
          "e_b": "something random",
          "e_c": "something random",
          "e_d": "something random",
          "e_e": "something random",
          "e_f": "something random"
        },
        {
          "e_a": "something random",
          "e_b": "something random",
          "e_c": "something random",
          "e_d": "something random",
          "e_e": "something random",
          "e_f": "something random"
        }
      ],
      "f": 0,
      "g": true,
      "h": {
        "h_a": [
          "something random"
        ],
        "h_b": [
          "something random"
        ],
        "h_c": [
          "something random"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "a": "Bla bla",
      "b": "Bla bla",
      "c": "Bla bla",
      "d": {
        "d_a": {
          "something random": 0,
          "something random": 4
        },
        "d_b": {
          "something random": "Bla bla",
          "something random": 0
        },
        "d_c": {
          "d_c_a": {
            "d_c_a_a": [
              "something random"
            ]
          },
          "d_c_b": {
            "d_c_b_a": [
              "something random",
              "something random",
              "something random"
            ]
          },
          "d_c_c": {
            "d_c_c_a": [
              "something random"
            ],
            "d_c_c_b": "something random"
          }
        }
      },
      "e": [
        {
          "e_a": "something random",
          "e_b": "something random",
          "e_c": "something random",
          "e_d": "something random",
          "e_e": "something random",
          "e_f": "something random"
        },
        {
          "e_a": "something random",
          "e_b": "something random",
          "e_c": "something random",
          "e_d": "something random",
          "e_e": "something random",
          "e_f": "something random"
        }
      ],
      "f": 0,
      "g": true,
      "h": {
        "h_a": [
          "something random"
        ],
        "h_b": [
          "something random"
        ],
        "h_c": [
          "something random"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I change `root` for `nono` tha validator throws an error, or if I remove `root`. But for the rest of the elements it always says that it's OK. Even if I change the names or delete them.

What I'm doing wrong?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was with the nesting of the `properties` field not being doing inside the field `items`.

Here is the fixed template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
    "title": "A title",
    "description": "A description",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "root": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "a": {
                        "description": "A description",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "b": {
                        "description": "A description",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "c": {
                        "description": "A description",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "d": {
                        "description": "A description",
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "d_a": {
                                "description": "A description",
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "d_b": {
                                "description": "A description",
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "d_c": {
                                "description": "A description",
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "d_c_a": {
                                        "description": "A description",
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "d_c_a_a": {
                                                "description": "A description",
                                                "type": "array",
                                                "items": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "minItems": 0,
                                                "uniqueItems": true
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "required": ["d_c_a_a"]
                                    },
                                    "d_c_b": {
                                        "description": "A description",
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "d_c_b_a": {
                                                "description": "A description",
                                                "type": "array",
                                                "items": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "minItems": 0,
                                                "uniqueItems": true
                                            },
                                        },
                                        "required": ["d_c_b_a"]
                                    },
                                    "d_c_c": {
                                        "description": "A description",
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "d_c_c_a": {
                                                "description": "A description",
                                                "type": "array",
                                                "items": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "minItems": 0,
                                                "uniqueItems": true
                                            },
                                            "d_c_c_b": {
                                                "description": "A description",
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "required": ["d_c_c_a", "d_c_c_b"]
                                    }
                                },
                                "required": ["d_c_a", "d_c_b", "d_c_c"]
                            },
                        },
                        "required": ["d_a", "d_b", "d_c"]
                    },
                    "e": {
                        "description": "A description",
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "e_a": {
                                    "description": "A description",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "e_b": {
                                    "description": "A description",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "e_c": {
                                    "description": "A description",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "e_d": {
                                    "description": "A description",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "e_e": {
                                    "description": "A description",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "e_f": {
                                    "description": "A description",
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": ["e_a", "e_b", "e_c", "e_d", "e_e", "e_f"]
                        },
                        "minItems": 1,
                        "uniqueItems": true,
                    },
                    "f": {
                        "description": "A description",
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "g": {
                        "description": "A description",
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "h": {
                        "description": "A description",
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "h_a": {
                                "description": "A description",
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "minItems": 0,
                                "uniqueItems": true
                            },
                            "h_b": {
                                "description": "A description",
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "minItems": 0,
                                "uniqueItems": true
                            },
                            "h_c": {
                                "description": "A description",
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "minItems": 0,
                                "uniqueItems": true
                            }
                        },
                        "required": ["h_a", "h_b", "h_c"]
                    }
                },
                "required": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
            },
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true,
        },
    },
    "required": ["root"]
}
```

And here a working example:

```
{
  "root": [
    {
      "a": "Bla bla",
      "b": "Bla bla",
      "c": "Bla bla",
      "d": {
        "d_a": {
          "something random": 0,
          "something random": 4
        },
        "d_b": {
          "something random": "Bla bla",
          "something random": 0
        },
        "d_c": {
          "d_c_a": {
            "d_c_a_a": [
              "something random"
            ]
          },
          "d_c_b": {
            "d_c_b_a": [
              "something random_1",
              "something random_2",
              "something random_3"
            ]
          },
          "d_c_c": {
            "d_c_c_a": [
              "something random"
            ],
            "d_c_c_b": "something random"
          }
        }
      },
      "e": [
        {
          "e_a": "something random_1",
          "e_b": "something random_2",
          "e_c": "something random_3",
          "e_d": "something random_4",
          "e_e": "something random_5",
          "e_f": "something random_6"
        },
        {
          "e_a": "something random_7",
          "e_b": "something random_8",
          "e_c": "something random_9",
          "e_d": "something random_10",
          "e_e": "something random_11",
          "e_f": "something random_12"
        }
      ],
      "f": 0,
      "g": true,
      "h": {
        "h_a": [
          "something random_1"
        ],
        "h_b": [
          "something random_2"
        ],
        "h_c": [
          "something random_3"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "a": "Bla bla",
      "b": "Bla bla",
      "c": "Bla bla",
      "d": {
        "d_a": {
          "something random": 0,
          "something random": 4
        },
        "d_b": {
          "something random": "Bla bla",
          "something random": 0
        },
        "d_c": {
          "d_c_a": {
            "d_c_a_a": [
              "something random"
            ]
          },
          "d_c_b": {
            "d_c_b_a": [
              "something random_1",
              "something random_2",
              "something random_3"
            ]
          },
          "d_c_c": {
            "d_c_c_a": [
              "something random"
            ],
            "d_c_c_b": "something random"
          }
        }
      },
      "e": [
        {
          "e_a": "something random_1",
          "e_b": "something random_2",
          "e_c": "something random_3",
          "e_d": "something random_4",
          "e_e": "something random_5",
          "e_f": "something random_6"
        },
        {
          "e_a": "something random_7",
          "e_b": "something random_8",
          "e_c": "something random_9",
          "e_d": "something random_10",
          "e_e": "something random_11",
          "e_f": "something random_12"
        }
      ],
      "f": 0,
      "g": true,
      "h": {
        "h_a": [
          "something random"
        ],
        "h_b": [
          "something random"
        ],
        "h_c": [
          "something random"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Regards!